# weird connection request on macos m1 nettop

Tags: macos, tcp

I see a weird connection request on macos m1 for nettop. This happens on other programs as well. these ips are blocked, but I am wondering what is causing this.

This happens specifically on macos, which is why I am asking this here

Is there a way to find out what is triggering this? While I showed the screenshot for Google Chrome, this happens with other applications as well.

[image: connection request]